# A pink-haired girl traveling into a different dimension/universe through a fridge door?

Tags: story-identification, comics

I'm trying to remember a comic book I once read.

The main character, a girl with pinkish hair, was once up late at night and getting a snack from the fridge. When she opened the door, it turned out to lead to an unreal universe/dimension and the girl fell through. She had to find help to get back to the door, which was still floating in the air.

The series had at least 2 books, maybe more.

Comment: Welcome, do you have an idea where you might've read this comic?

Comment: Could it be a Doctor Strange storyline?

Comment: It used to be at the slatsic book fairs and in classrooms. No I don't think it could be a Doctor Strange storyline